# Refresh projector in Orchard CMS using AJAX

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, orchardcms

There is a projector and a query that I have created using the admin panel and filtering the query by content-type "Course".

And the same page I am using a pop-up form using jQuery dialog, that creates a new element of content-type "Course" using AJAX, that is working fine, but after creating it I would like to close the dialog and **refresh the Projector** to display the item I have just created.

Which method should I call using AJAX to refresh the customized projector ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, location.reload() should work.